# Html5 <audio> не работает перемотка в google chrome

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте есть проблема.В `Google chrome  54.0.2840.99 m`  не работает перемотка при воспроизведении аудио файлов.

```
<audio class="callPlayer" type="audio/mp3" src="/GetAudio?path=" + audiopath + \"" controls></audio> \n
```

контроллер который возвращает аудио запись из массива байтов выглядит вот так.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetAudio(string path)
        {
            byte[] audiobytes = _callRepo.GetAudioByPath(path);
            if (audiobytes != null)
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(audiobytes, 0, audiobytes.Length);
                return new FileStreamResult(stream, "audio/mp3");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

В остальных браузерах всё работает нормально.С чем это может быть связано?Аудио проигрывается но его нельзя перематывать. Пробовал проигрывать аудио из локального пути,работает нормально.Но загружать с базы данных файл в локальную папку не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Исправил тем что добавил в заголовок в контроллере следующее:
header('Content-Length: ' . размер файла);
header('accept-ranges: bytes');