# HTML5 audio. Не работает перемотка в Хроме

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка, аудио, web-audio

Есть html5 audio тэг в котором проигрывается mp3 с удаленного сервера (запись разговора телефонии). Подгружается и проигрывает нормально. Проблема, что в хроме невозможно перемотать запись. Поиском нашел тут предложение:
[Html5 <audio> не работает перемотка в google chrome](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597264/html5-audio-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-google-chrome)

Рекомендуют добавить заголовки:
header('Content-Length: ' . размер файла); header('accept-ranges: bytes');

Проблема в том, что файл-то не на моем сервере лежит :(. Можно ли с этим что-то придумать?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была исключительно в заголовках. Мой mp3 файл приходил с вот такими заголовками:

---

```
Content-Length: 16416
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

---

А вот так выглядят заголовки для корректного аудио файла:

---

```
accept-ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 163584
Content-Range: bytes 0-163583/163584
content-type: audio/mpeg
```

---